# Javascript: splitting an array of structures onto arrays of its elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, structure

Suppose I have an array of structures r[i]. Every structure consists of three numeric elements elements x, y and z. How to convert this array of structures onto 3 numeric arrays x[i], y[i] and z[i] ? 
There is of course a dumb way of traversing all elements of the array, but is there a smarter one?

Comment: IF you want to actually convert it, the only way is the dumb way. If you just want to access it differently, then there are ways

Comment: Any way you do it, you will be looping.

Answer (score 0):

Looping over them is probably the easiest way.

```
var x = [], y = [], z = [];

r.forEach(function(i) {
  x.push(i.x);
  y.push(i.y);
  z.push(i.z);
});
```